# Syncfusion tab control's value doesn't refresh when value of elements changes

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion

I have a syncfusion tab control with few pages and it is showing the values that are set in state variables, whenever I change values by setstate, I expect that the values in the tabs get updated but unfortunately it doesn't happen.

I even set  enablePersistence="true" but had no effect.

if I put input field in the form, by clicking the test button, it will be refreshed by the new values but not the one in tab control.

your advices would be appreciated.

here is the code:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export default class FormDataBinding extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.state = { name: "name", family: "family" };

    this.headertext = [
      { text: "Twitter", iconCss: "e-twitter" },
    ];
  }
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  tabContent1 = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>

        <p>thes controls are inside Tab Component</p>
        <div>
          {/* it's not working because it's inside  tabComponent */}
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.name}
            key="nameKey1"
            id="nameId1"
            style={{ width: "500px" }}
          ></input>
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.family}
            key="familyID1"
            id="familyKey1"
            style={{ width: "500px" }}
          ></input>
          <button onClick={this.btnClick.bind(this)}>click hear</button>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  btnClick = () => {
    var newName = "name :" + new Date().toTimeString();
    var familyName = "family : " + new Date().toTimeString();

    this.setState({ name: newName });
    this.setState({ family: familyName });
    this.UpdateStateInstantly(newName);
    this.ShowTabs();
  };
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ShowTabs = () => {
    return (
      <TabComponent
        enablePersistence="true"
        heightAdjustMode="Auto"
        id="defaultTab"
      >
        <TabItemsDirective>

          {/* ------------< Tab1 >------------- */}
          <TabItemDirective
            presentation={true}
            header={this.headertext[0]}

            content={this.tabContent1}
          />


        </TabItemsDirective>
      </TabComponent>
    );
  };
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="control-pane">
        <div className="control-section tab-control-section">
          {/*-------------------*/}
          <button onClick={this.btnClick.bind(this)}>click here</button>
          <br />
          {/* //-----------------------------------< Tabs >--------------------- */}
          {this.ShowTabs()}
          {/* //--------------------------------------------------------------- */}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have achieved your requirement using the custom data in template in the content property. We have passed template and data to `Tab` content for retrieving `setState` changes. This issue reason is because the `setstate` is not immediately mutate inside the `Tab` content template.  Kindly refer to the following code.

```
tabContent1 = (data, data1) => {  
    return (  
      <React.Fragment>  
        <p>thes controls are inside Tab Component</p>  
        <div>  
          {/* it's not working because it's inside  tabComponent */}  
          <input  
            type="text"  
            value={data.text}  
            key="nameKey1"  
            id="nameId1"  
            style={{ width: "500px" }}  
          />  
          <br />  
          <input  
            type="text"  
            value={data1.textval}  
            key="familyID1"  
            id="familyKey1"  
            style={{ width: "500px" }}  
          />  

          <button onClick={this.btnClick.bind(this)}>click hear</button>  
        </div>  
      </React.Fragment>  
    );  
  };  
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  btnClick = () => {  
    debugger;  
    var newName = "name :" + new Date().toTimeString();  
    var familyName = "family : " + new Date().toTimeString();  

    this.setState({ name: newName });  
    this.setState({ family: familyName });  
    //this.UpdateStateInstantly(newName);  
    // this.ShowTabs(); // no need to call this method again  

  };  
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  ShowTabs = () => {  
    return (  
      <TabComponent  
        ref={tab => (this.tab = tab)}  
        enablePersistence="true"  
        heightAdjustMode="Auto"  
        id="defaultTab"  
      >  
        <TabItemsDirective>  
          {console.log("ShowTabs1")}  
          {/* ------------< Tab1 >------------- */}  
          <TabItemDirective  
            presentation={true}  
            header={this.headertext[0]}  
            content={{  
              template: this.tabContent1,  
              data: { text: this.state.name, textval: this.state.family }  
            }}  
          />  
          {console.log("ShowTabs2")}  
        </TabItemsDirective>  
      </TabComponent>  
    );  
  };
```

We have attached the below sample for your reference.

Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-cartwright-o8isb

Comment: In Syncfusion versions > 18.2.54 this is broken. Using `content= {{ template }}` results in the tab being rendered as literally `[object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

The state update is asynchrounous, so you have to use this syntax to be sure that the functions UpdateStateInstantly and ShowTabs are triggered right after the state update, and not before:

```
btnClick = () => {
    var newName = "name :" + new Date().toTimeString();
    var familyName = "family : " + new Date().toTimeString();

    this.setState({ name: newName, family: familyName }, () => {
       this.UpdateStateInstantly(newName);
       this.ShowTabs(); 
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I get compile error on: this.UpdateStateInstantly(newName);

Comment: I updated the answer. I forgot to put the functions inside  () => {...}, so that they correctly point to the component where they're called from

Comment: Thanks again, after that I get error: "TypeError: _this.UpdateStateInstantly is not a function". as its not required , I commented that line, now ShowTabs is running but the same problem still exists: showTabs is supposed to run tabContent1 but it still doesn't get called for showing the updates

Answer (score 0):

As I was using Syncfusion Tab component, I asked their support team and fortunately they guided me to the right answer :

```
TabContent1 = (data, data1) => { 
return ( 
  <React.Fragment> 

    <div> 
      {/* it's not working because it's inside  tabComponent */} 
      <input 
        type="text" 
        value={data.text} 
        key="nameKey1" 
        id="nameId1" 
        style={{ width: "500px" }} 
      /> 
      <br /> 
      <input 
        type="text" 
        value={data1.textval} 
        key="familyID1" 
        id="familyKey1" 
        style={{ width: "500px" }} 
      /> 

      <button onClick={this.btnClick.bind(this)}>click hear</button> 
    </div> 
  </React.Fragment> 
); 
}; 

  btnClick = () => { 

     var newName = "name :" + new Date().toTimeString(); 
     var familyName = "family : " + new Date().toTimeString(); 

     this.setState({ name: newName }); 
     this.setState({ family: familyName }); 
  }; 

  ShowTabs = () => { 
    return ( 
      <TabComponent 
      ref={tab => (this.tab = tab)} 
      enablePersistence="true" 
      heightAdjustMode="Auto" 
      id="defaultTab" 
    > 
    <TabItemsDirective> 
      {console.log("ShowTabs1")} 
      {/* ------------< Tab1 >------------- */} 
      <TabItemDirective 
        presentation={true} 
        header={this.headertext[0]} 

        // MAGIC IS THESE TWO LINES IN CONTENT
        content={{ 
          template: this.tabContent1, 
          data: { text: this.state.name, textval: this.state.family } 
        }} 
      /> 

    </TabItemsDirective> 
  </TabComponent> 
);
```

};